# Show that $(1-\sqrt{x})/(1+\sqrt{x})$ is injective for $x>0$

Tags: calculus, functions

I have just started my course in calculus and would need some guidance here. If possible, don't give complete solutions, since I need all training I can possibly get :)

**Problem.** The function $f$ is defined by $$f(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}\,,\:\: x>0\,.$$
Show that $f$ is injective in as many ways as possible.

**My thoughts.**

I have started by showing that $f$ is strictly increasing by showing that $f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)>0$ for any positive $\epsilon$ (we have not introduced derivatives yet, so I guess that was the best way to do it, but *perhaps there are more efficient methods?*). By the definition of injectivity, that implies that $f$ also is injective. Is that an acceptable solution?

I also tried to find an inverse by solving $y=f(x)$ for $x$. This gave me $$\sqrt{x}=\frac{1-y}{1+y}\Longrightarrow x=\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)^2,$$ *but I am not entirely sure what I should do about the implication. Actually, I am not even sure if it's a problem.*

Except this, I also wonder if there are any other ways that I can show the injectivity of $f$.

Comment: Your approach is fine. Now suppose that there are $x_1$ and $x_2$ so that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=y$. What does your equation say about $x_1$ and $x_2$?

Comment: It says that $$f(x_1)=f(x_2)=y\Longrightarrow x_1=x_2=\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right),$$ which is logically equivalent with the definition of injectivity, $$x_1\neq x_2\Longrightarrow f(x_1)\neq f(x_2).$$ So, I suppose that means that I don't need to show that $$x=\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)\Longrightarrow \sqrt{x}=\frac{1-y}{1+y},$$
right? (But if I wanted to, how would I do it?)

Comment: Note that your function is *decreasing*.

Comment: Just show the function is a homeomorphism onto some subset of the real line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show injectivity, you need to show that if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, then $x_1=x_2$. Your approach works just fine. Suppose that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=y$. Your equation says that
$$
x_1=\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)^2
$$
and
$$
x_2=\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)^2
$$
That is, $x_1=x_2$.

Answer (score 1):

You can write $f(x)$ as follows:
$$
f(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}=\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{x}}-1\,,\:\: x>0\,.
$$
Then if you accept that $g(x)=\sqrt x$ is injective then $f(x)$ should be injective too.

Answer (score 1):

To show that
$f(x)$ is strictly decreasing,
just note that
$1-\sqrt{x}$
is strictly decreasing
and
$1+\sqrt{x}$
is strictly increasing.

Then prove that
if $a(x)$ is strictly decreasing
and
$b(x)$ is strictly increasing
and positive,
then
$\dfrac{a(x)}{b(x)}$
is strictly decreasing.

We want to show that
$\dfrac{a(x+h)}{b(x+h)}
< \dfrac{a(x)}{b(x)}
$.

$\begin{align}
\frac{a(x+h)}{b(x+h)}
&< \frac{a(x)}{b(x+h)} \quad \text{ (since } a(x+h) < a(x))\\
&< \frac{a(x)}{b(x)} \quad \text{ (since } b(x+h) > b(x) > 0)\\
\end{align}
$

That's all you need.

Comment: Okay. I understand how $$a(x+h)<a(x)\Longleftrightarrow\frac{a(x+h)}{b(x+h)}<\frac{a(x)}{b(x+h)},$$ but I can't convince myself that $$b(x+h)>b(x)>0 \Longleftrightarrow \frac{a(x)}{b(x+h)}<\frac{a(x)}{b(x)}$$ for $a(x)\leq 0$.